# Is there a tool for Java RMI testing like SoapUI does for web services?

Tags: java, testing, rmi

I'm looking for a (GUI?) tool that can connect to RMI services and display the results.  Sort of like how SoapUI allows you to specify a WSDL, generated test input and execute the call.  I would like to specify an RMI destination (i.e. rmi://server:port/package/class.method(parameters, ...) ) and test the RMI call.

Bonus if it can save the test parameters and repeat the test later, so that I can provide the tests to QA.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by Segphault you should have a look at http://www.itko.com/products/java.jsp.

You can also try JMeter RMI sampler from [here](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/09/14/use-jmeter-to-load-test-rmi-remote-method-invocation-server/).

Comment: I already use jMeter but have to keep coding custom samplers for each RMI service.  This looks perfect.

Comment: Does my answer not qualify for bounty ? :)

Comment: Sorry forgot to click the + bounty button.

Comment: Just had a look - it is completely impossible to find anything to actually download and try...

Comment: Link is not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.itko.com/products/java.jsp) looks promising, but I've never tried it and it isn't free.  It looks like you can request an evaluation. YMMV.